# ReportViewer control not working when AsyncRendering set to false

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I just converted a Reporting project from .net 2.0 to .net 4.0 using the Visual Studio converter.

Now the ReportViewer control is not working. The DataSet is properly set but the Report is not working.

I changed the AsyncRendering property of ReportViewer to false and then it worked. But now the paging controls are not working in the Report. And since for paging to work, I need to change the AsyncRendering to true again.

Can anyone tell why the Report is not working when AsyncRendering is set to true? Please help.

Comment: Maybe your ReportViewer is outdated. What is your ReportViewer version ? Has it been upgraded as part of the conversion process ?

Comment: yes it has been upgraded. The version is 10

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your web.config for reportviewer configuration like assembly version and etc.